# Class App\Http\Controllers\EpisodeController does not exist

Tags: laravel, deployment

**I am new user in laravel. so , I need help about routes**

============

## *web.php*

```
Auth::routes();

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//Route::get('/channelpage', 'ChannelController@channelpage');

Route::get('/teledrama', 'TeledramaController@index');
Route::post('/teledrama',[
    'uses'=>'TeledramaController@create',
    'as'=>'teledrama'
]);

Route::get('/episode', 'EpisodeController@index');
Route::post('/episode',[
    'uses'=>'EpisodeController@create',
    'as'=>'episode'
]);

Route::get('/channel', 'ChannelController@index');
Route::post('/channel', [
    'uses'=>'ChannelController@create',
    'as'=>'channel'
]);
```

============================================

## api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

//channel

//Route::post('/channel','ChannelController@create');

Route::get('/channels','ChannelController@show');

Route::get('/channel/{id}','ChannelController@showbyid');

Route::put('/channelupdate/{id}','ChannelController@updatebyid');

Route::delete('/channeldelete/{id}','ApiController@deletebyid');

//teledrama

//Route::post('/teledrama','TeledramaController@create');

Route::get('/teledramas/{ch_Id}','TeledramaController@show');

Route::get('/teledrama/{id}','TeledramaController@showbyid');

Route::put('/teledramaupdate/{id}','TeledramaController@updatebyid');

Route::delete('/teledramadelete/{id}','TeledramaController@deletebyid');

//episode

//Route::post('/episode','EpisodeController@create');

Route::get('/episodes/{te_Id}','EpisodeController@show');

Route::get('/episode/{id}','EpisodeController@showbyid');

Route::put('/episodeupdate/{id}','EpisodeController@updatebyid');

Route::delete('/episodedelete/{id}','EpisodeController@deletebyid');
```

## episode.blade.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Jayani
 * Date: 10/11/2019
 * Time: 11:29 AM
 */
?>
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container is-fluid box">
    <div class="tabs is-centered is-large">
        <ul>
            <li :class="{'is-active': isActive('video')}" @click="getFiles('video')">
                <a>
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-film"></i></span>
                    <span>Episodes</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-details">
        <form class="needs-validation" action="{{ route('episode') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-row">
                @if($arry['teledramas'] !=null)
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="teledrama_content">Select Teledrama</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" name="te_Id">

                        @foreach($arry['teledramas'] as $teledramas)

                        <option value="{{$teledramas->id}}"> {{$teledramas->te_Name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                @endif

                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationTooltip04">Video ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ep_videoID" name="ep_videoID"
                           placeholder="Input Video ID" onkeypress="function loadData()">

                    <div class="valid-tooltip">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <br>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Video ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Episode Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Episode Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($arry['episodes'] as $episodes)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$episodes->ep_videoID}}</td>
            <td> {{$episodes->ep_Title}}</td>
            <td> {{$episodes->ep_Description}}</td>

        </tr>


        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <nav class="pagination is-centered" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination" v-if="pagination.last_page > 1"
         v-cloak>
        <a class="pagination-previous" @click.prevent="changePage(1)" :disabled="pagination.current_page <= 1">First
            page</a>
        <a class="pagination-previous" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)"
           :disabled="pagination.current_page <= 1">Previous</a>
        <a class="pagination-next" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)"
           :disabled="pagination.current_page >= pagination.last_page">Next page</a>
        <a class="pagination-next" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.last_page)"
           :disabled="pagination.current_page >= pagination.last_page">Last page</a>
        <ul class="pagination-list">
            <li v-for="page in pages">
                <a class="pagination-link" :class="isCurrentPage(page) ? 'is-current' : ''"
                   @click.prevent="changePage(page)">
                    @{{ page }}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
@endsection
```

error------

> ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Controllers\EpisodeController
>   does not exist
>
> This laravel project running well on localhost but it's not work when it deploy on server

Comment: Error says that `EpisodeController` does not exist? is it exist in the controller folder make sure?

Comment: your EpisodeController is not exist. if it work on localhost but not work on server, maybe it because your uppercase and lowercase. have you check your file name and class name? because server is more sensitive about uppercase and lowercase than localhost. so sometimes, the code that running on localhost give error warning on server..